# Get the build number before *CoreCompile* phase?

Tags: c#, msbuild

If I define a program's assembly attribute like below:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

I got a nice auto-incremented versioning when checking the binary details in explorer:

[image]

I wish to retrieve this number **before build**: in my *MSBuild* target which is defined with:

```
<Target Name="MyNiceTarget" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
```

Can I do this anyhow? As the builder hasn't compiled the core yet, is this information at all available, or it's too early?

Goal: to retrieve the version of "1.0.8218.27256" and update something else which needs to be also included as assembly attribute into the executable:

```
File version: 1.0.8218.27256
Product version: 1.0.8218.27256-mycomment
```

*Product version* can be updated with `AssemblyInformationalVersion`. But can I somehow retrieve the version which *File version* will use?

Answer (score 0):

The information is not available prior to building. The '*' is not an increment of a prior value that has been stored somewhere. Instead the value is generated from the current date and time.

You can use the [`AssemblyMetadataAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblymetadataattribute?view=net-6.0) to add information to the assembly and have your code retrieve and display the appropriate metadata.